# Another Jquery animation return issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im new to js and don't know enough about jquery to be able to manipulate other people's solutions into my own code, so I figured I'd ask my own to get a specific answer.

I'm working on an interactive garage app where you can change the color of cars and the wheels as well. I have separate color selectors that animate onto the stage (from the bottom) for the cars and wheels, but both in the same position.

Basically, when a user clicks "change car color" it animates the car color selectors into place, and when they click "change wheel color" it hides the car color selectors and animates the wheel color selectors.

That being said, I want to return the selectors to their original positions when the other is clicked so that they don't keep sliding up the screen, and the user can keep switching between the two color selector options as many times as they want.

Here's the code I'm working with, any help would be great:

```
$("#carcolor").click(function(){

    $("#colors2").hide();
    $("#colors1").show();
    $("#pink").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},1500);    
    $("#yellow").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},2000);
    $("#green").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},2500);
    $("#blue").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},3000);    
    $("#purple").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},3500);
    $("#red").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},4000);


$("#wheelcolor").click(function(){  

    $("#colors1").hide();
    $("#colors2").show();   
    $("#pink2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},1500);    
    $("#yellow2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},2000);
    $("#green2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},2500);
    $("#blue2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},3000);    
    $("#purple2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},3500);
    $("#red2").animate({
        bottom:'+=200px'},4000);
```

Comment: can you post the html too, or create a fiddle so we can see what's going on?

Comment: It's too long to leave in a comment, and I've never used fiddle. Sorry for the noobishness. What exactly do you need to know?

I basically just need to have the location of the divs reset to their original positions if the indicator is clicked a second time, or if the other indicator is clicked. 

What's happening is that if the "change car color" button is clicked a second time the divs animate up again from their current position (moving them up the screen)

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code, but i think i know what you mean. i'll see what i can do.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it's my first time on the site so thanks for bearing with me haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**is this close?**

I wasn't sure how your markup looks, so I just put it together the way I wanted, and tried to simplify things some.

**EDIT**
although my example doesn't match perfectly, it does illustrate a better way to accomplish the task, so I'll leave it here.

```
$('.box').each(function() {
    var box = $(this);
    var that = $(this).children('.colors');
    var head = $(this).children('h2');
    var speed = 200;
    head.on('click', function(){
        if(that.hasClass('on')) {
            that.slideUp(speed).children().stop().animate({bottom: '-30px'}, speed).end().removeClass('on');
        } else {
            $('.on').removeClass('on').slideUp(speed).children().attr('style','');
            that.slideDown(speed).addClass('on').children().each(function(i) {
                $(this).stop().animate({bottom: '+=30px'}, speed*i);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/DGUeU/

**EDIT**

In order for this to work the way it should, you should really redo the whole thing. Your html is all kinds of wonky, css isn't aiding javascript, and the javascript is way to verbose.

I think I have it working here, let me know. 
http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/y47wn/8/

Comment: Not quite, but what I need is in there somewhere haha. Let me sign up for fiddle and get back to you with some proper context. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, and I hate wasting peoples time, so for that I apologize.

I threw together a fiddle, but I used slices instead of css for the elements so the fiddle is just broken images, but you can get the idea from it.

Basically, you click the middle img, and when the rest animates in it's the two on the far right that control the color selectors which you'll see animate up from the bottom

http://jsfiddle.net/dsighn/y47wn/

Comment: right now, I have an extra animation on the bottom far right, or "wheel color" img, so that when it is clicked it animates the "car color" selectors back, but its a bandaid and doesn't work the other way because users may choose to change the wheel colors first...If that makes sense

Comment: Haha yeah, I figured as much, but it's my first time working with Jquery/js so I'm learning as I go. 

It's a project for a class, so if there's a way to help me solve that problem without simplifying everything then I can learn from there and do things differently next time :)

Thanks again for all of your help so far.

Comment: I edited your fiddle and think I got it working like you want, check the fiddle link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, thanks a ton. I know it's a complete mess, My whole class has kind of been left to our own to figure this stuff out so like I said, I'm learning as I go. 

Thanks again for your time and patience, you rock